# How to troubleshoot a custom hosts file that's breaking a bank site's functionality

Tags: javascript, form-submit, hosts, submit-button, hosts-file

I am using a crowdsourced hosts file with over 40,000 entries to prevent intrusive advertising and tracking.  Something in the file seems to be interfering with the functionality of the Citibank website, which makes a "submit" form javascript button on the wire transfers page non-functional.

I have eventually narrowed the problem down to the hosts file, because the problem is identical in Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.  Upon clearing the hosts file, the submit button worked and the transfer went through.

What seems to be happening is that the site is calling out for a third-party tracker, and upon failing to reach it, renders some (or all) javascript on the page non-functional.  How do I identify the entry or entries in the hosts file that are messing with the submit button's functionality?

Comment: You could try examining the traffic with Fiddler.

Comment: I guess check the netwerk tab in devtools and search for the match

Comment: Check which domain the submit button calls and delete it from the hosts file.

Comment: @ArielAlvarado I am on the consumer end of this problem.  No access to the site's code, obviously.

Comment: @KnocksX as Jonathan said, try using the network tab in devtools (f12 -> network)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan.  The domain was isnare.com, some sort of fraud prevention.